# QFT: Limits in Time Ordered Correlation Function Derivation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, field-theory, correlation-functions, ground-state

**Background**

In part of the derivation for the time ordered correlation function I have the following equation (This equation I am fine with - it is what follows that I am not),

$$
\int\mathcal{D}\varphi(x_1)\varphi(x_2)
exp\left(
    i\int^{T}_{-T}
 d^4x\mathcal{L}
\right)
=
\left\langle
\varphi_b(\underline{x})
\left|
e^{-iHT}
T
\left\{
\varphi_H(x_2)
\varphi_H(x_1)
\right\}
e^{-iHT}
\right|
\varphi_a(\underline{x})
\right\rangle
$$

where $T$ is time ordering operator, $\varphi_H$ denotes a Heisenberg operator and $\int\mathcal{D}\varphi$ is a functional integral.

**Problem Area**

In this context we then look at the following and introduce a set of states $n$,
$$
e^{-iHT}
|
\varphi_a
\rangle
=
\sum_n
e^{-iE_nT}
\left|
\left.
n
\right\rangle
\left\langle
n
\right|
\varphi_a
\right\rangle
$$

From here we take the limit (time) as $T\to\infty(1+i\delta)$...

In my notes I have that this gives,

$$
\tag{1}
e^{-iHT}
|
\varphi_a
\rangle
=
\sum_n
e^{-iE_n\infty(1+i\delta)}
\left|
\left.
n
\right\rangle
\left\langle
n
\right|
\varphi_a
\right\rangle
$$

**What follows is the bit I am stuck on:**
In my notes I have that 
$$
\tag{2}
\sum_n
e^{-iE_n\infty(1+i\delta)}
\left|
\left.
n
\right\rangle
\left\langle
n
\right|
\varphi_a
\right\rangle
=
\left|
\left.
0
\right\rangle
\left\langle
0
\right|
\varphi_a
\right\rangle
$$

I can't see how this happens...If I mechanically expand out the exponential I get the follwing,

$$
e^{-i E_n\infty}e^{-\infty E_n\delta}
\to 0
$$
My issues is kind of obvious in that I loose all my physics! :(

Comment: Solved: A course mate pointed out we assume $E_n = 0$ which means the vacuum energy state contributes in the limit.